# Tooltip Bootstrap 4 wont show default style

Tags: javascript, tooltip

I added a tooltip to a text using data-toggle. The tooltip shows but without any style applied to it. I'm using a JS library called popper.js.

I'm new to JS so i just copy-paste the code and library following an example, it works in my first link with tooltip (mail) but the second link ( word javascript) doesn't display the tooltip with style.

This is the example i used https://www.quackit.com/html/html_editors/scratchpad/?example=/bootstrap/bootstrap_4/tutorial/bootstrap_4_tooltips_buttons

I'm attaching screenshots [tooltip displaying correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TK7z4.png)[tooltip displaying wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZYzG.png)

Here's the code:

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">


  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
  });
  </script>
  
 </head>
 <body>
 
  
  <div id="center">
   <div class="intro-header">
     <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1>first text</h1>
        <!--line-->
        <hr class="line2" align="center" width="80%">
       </div>
       <div class="contact">
        <span class="script">second text</span>
        <span class="sans-serif">
        <a href="mailto:hello@randomood.com?Subject=Hello" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Say Hi!" data-placement="bottom" class="no-style" 
        target="_top">hello@randomood.com</a>
                <div class="skills-box">
        <span class="sans-serif">skills <br> other <a href="#" data-togle="tooltip" title="currently learning" data-placement="bottom" class="no-stylex"> JavaScript</a> </span>
        
       </div>
        
        </span>
       </div>

       
       
      </div>
     </div>
   </div> 
  </div>


  

  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  <!-- Initialize Bootstrap functionality -->
  <script>
  // Initialize tooltip component
  $(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
  })

  // Initialize popover component
  $(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
  })
  </script>

 </body>
```

Comment: Try to wrap your code in `$(document).ready(function()
{

});`

Comment: I just added it and added the link with the tooltip that is working. My second link-tooltip won't work. Any advices?